# C# check if items in a List<t> exist and increment if it does

Tags: c#, list

I got a CSV file that I read and get 3 values from. The values are: `name, date, volume`.

I want to do the following, read the file and write it to a `List<T>` but with a little change. For each item in the CSV file I want to check if the `List<T>` already contains a line with that `name` and `date`. If it does I want the `volume` in the list increased with +1 if it does not it has to add the line from the csv file to the `List<T>` with `volume = 1`

So basically i want something like this.

```
 List<T> CsvList = new List<T>();
 foreach (var item in CSV)
 {
     object o = new object(item.name, item.date, item.volume)
     if(CsvList.name.contains(o.name) && CsvList.date.contains(o.date){
     //Increase the volume of the item in the CsvList where name == o.name and date == o.date;
     }
 }
```

Is this possible to achieve in only a C# application. I can write it to a database and check in that database if those values exist, but I don't want to do this with a database.

Comment: instead of a list you should use a dictionary where the key is your item and the value is your counter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using `GroupBy` linq extension for this.

Group them on (name,date) and calculate the volume count

```
CSV.GroupBy(x=> new {x.name, x.date})
   .Select(x=>  new object(x.Key.name, x.Key.date, x.Sum(s=> s.volume))) 
                // I'm not sure are you referring to system.object? use appropriate type.
                // or remove object so that you will have an anonymous object.
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Just wanted to write the same, but note that there is no such `object` constructor. So you'll need an anonymous type or create an own type.

Comment: That's true, even I was wonder how it compiled to OP. Anyway I'll add that point as an additional info. Thanks @RenéVogt

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from the question, here goes:

**Count the number of times**

If you just want to know how often an item occurs, you can use a `Dictionary` with some key. The key can be a `Tuple<string, string>` or anything else that's `IEquatable` (implements `Equals` and `GetHashCode`).

e.g.:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, int> dict;
int count;
var key = new Tuple<string, string>(name, date);
dict.TryGetValue(key, out count); // defaults to 0.
dict[key] = count + 1;
```

**Lookup & change**

Similarly, if you want to modify the class `T` (note: it cannot be a struct!), you can use a `Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, T>` and store the `Name` and `Date`'s in the dictionary.

Also, you might want to add a condition like `public class CsvReader<T> where T : ISomeInterfaceAllowingModification` so you know T to have a property or method that you can use for the changes.

Something like this:

```
// "T read" is the read line from the CSV.

T value;
var tup = new Tuple<string, string>(name, date);
if (myDictionary.TryGetValue(tup, out value))
{
    // modify value by calling the interface method / using the interface property
    value.AddVolume();
}
else 
{
    // add value to list and dictionary
    myDictionary.Add(tup, read);
    myList.Add(read);
}
```